# Which object does WPF WebBrowser.Document property actually return?

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control, mshtml

From the MSDN the return type is just "object".

But this object returned could be cast-ed to mshtml.HTMLDocument if you want to manipulate the elements, or the very same object could be cast-ed to (mshtml.HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event) if you want to register event callback.

In MSHTML [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741322%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), there are so many interfaces defined. But it is unclear that how those interfaces be used with the WPF WebBrowser.Document object

If the returned object is a COM object, so **What is it?**
What is the different between this WPF [WebBrowser.Document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.document%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and the windows form [WebBrower.Document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.document%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Example code:

```
mshtml.HTMLDocument doc = (mshtml.HTMLDocument)_browser.Document;
IHTMLElement bt = doc.getElementById("123");

mshtml.HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event iEvent = (mshtml.HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event)_browser.Document;
iEvent.onclick += new HTMLDocumentEvents2_onclickEventHandler(ClickEventHandler);
```

Answer (score 1):

Windows Forms

- `WebBrowser.Document` [returns a .NET wrapper to the COM document object, if it's an HTMLDocument](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/WebBrowser.cs,3013ded900e5031e)

WPF

- `WebBrowser.Document` [returns the actual COM object, even if it's not an HTMLDocument](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/WebBrowser.cs,5c0f51a4876c602f).

Comment: The WPF link is currently broken